# Flutter, make number picker with numbers fontSize progressively smaller

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, carousel, numberpicker

friends!
I want to make a number picker on Flutter, where the font size of numbers (not selected) progressively decreases to each side and changes the colors.

[image]

As shown in the picture.

Is anybody has a task like that? Any solution?

p.s. Tried to use package [NumberPicker](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker/example)

No results!

Answer (score 0):

i never used NumberPicker, but here is

https://pub.dev/documentation/numberpicker/latest/numberpicker/NumberPicker-class.html

decoration properties which help to change selected value size and color.

Comment: I can change selected values style, but not selected all one style. I wanted to make then descending fontsize.